# App not verified when tried submitting to google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I built a website and my website does have sensitive scopes. So I have declared all the scopes and submitted to Google. Its been more then 7days and my consent hasn't been approved yet. Kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

The verification process can take several weeks. Please see the FAQ [1].

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-time